# How can I locate where a specific function is being called within the Program using Ghidra?

Tags: ghidra

Let says my Program use this `FUN_180811be0` function, discovered by disassembling the code within Ghidra:

[image]

Where do I locate the points of the program where this call is being called?

If I search for funtions it just show to me it:

[image]

I need to locate point of code where its being called; for example here, within the function `FUN_180606830`, I can see the call to `thunk_FUN_18051a380`:

[image]

How can I find it starting from the target function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments in green, XREFs, are all of the references to that function that Ghidra could identify. Start with those to find what you are looking for.